# Is there a significant difference between: if not a == 'bar' and if a != 'bar'?

Tags: python

Is this just two ways to write the same code? Is there any functional difference I should be aware of?

```
>>> a = 'foo'
>>> if not a == 'bar':
...     'its not'
... 
'its not'
>>> if a != 'bar':
...     'its not'
... 
'its not'
```

Comment: When you used `timeit` what did you find?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In python, to check whether or not an object is equal or not equal to another object, special functions are called.  `__eq__` is called to check `==`, while `__ne__` is called to check `!=`

In general, an object could define `__ne__` differently than `__eq__`.

E.g.

```
class Junk(object):
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return False

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False

j = Junk()
print not j == 1
print j != 1
```

This yields:

```
True
False
```

However, this would be especially evil...  You usually should never have to worry about this.

Comment: Strange!  What is an example where one would actually want for `a.__ne__(b) != not a.__eq__(b)` ?

Comment: That's a great question!  I honestly can't think of one... However, there are cases where this issues raises its head.  Numpy `ndarray`s are a good example.  `somearray != 1` will return a boolean array, while `not somearray == 1` will raise an error.  This is because `__eq__` and `__ne__` return boolean arrays, but `not somearray` is (deliberately) undefined.  (This probably seems confusing if you haven't worked with numpy much. My apologies if this example makes no sense!)

Answer (score 1):

`not a == b` gets translated to a call to `not a.__eq__(b)`, while `a != b` gets translated to a call to `a.__ne__(b)`. For the most part (pretty much every normal object I can think of), `__ne__` is defined as `def __ne__(self, other): not self.__eq__(other)`, so there's no functional difference. However, you could easily create a psychotic object that was both equal and not equal to other values, just by overriding `__ne__` in the right way (though I can't think of a case where that would make sense right now).

On the flip side, the builtin objects probably implement `a != b` in manner that's slightly faster than `not a == b`, but probably not by any noticable amount.